# SmackException$NoResponseException in jmeter when try to login

Tags: jmeter, xmpp, ejabberd, jmeter-plugins

We are developing chat application.For that application, i have to do load testing on XMPP server using JMeter. So refer this site.https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xmpp-load-testing-the-ultimate-guide/ As per the site, connected with server successfully.But when i try to login.But facing org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.How do i proceed by overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For ejabberd the recommended load tool is RTB: https://github.com/processone/rtb
It's written by the same company that develops ejabberd.

Comment: Can u suggest me to follow any tutorial for RTB